# Is there a way to word-wrap long words in a div?

Tags: css, html, word-wrap

I know Internet Explorer has a word-wrap style, but I'd like to know if there is a cross-browser method of doing so to text in a div.

Preferably CSS but JavaScript snippets would work ok too.

I'm referring to long strings.

Comment: Word wrapping happens by default. Do you mean wrapping when there *aren't* separate words?

Answer (score 325, accepted):

Reading the original comment, rutherford is looking for a **cross-browser** way to wrap **unbroken** text (inferred by his use of word-wrap for IE, designed to break unbroken strings).

```
/* Source: http://snipplr.com/view/10979/css-cross-browser-word-wrap */
.wordwrap { 
   white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS3 */   
   white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */    
   white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera <7 */   
   white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */    
   word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE */
}
```

I've used this class for a bit now, and works like a charm.  (note: I've only tested in FireFox and IE)

Comment: Old post, but it doesn't appear to render spaces when IE is in quirks mode.

Comment: I'm using Firefox 24.6.0, and the `word-wrap: break-word` is what actually worked.

Comment: `Word-wrap: break-word` although created by Microsoft is now is part of the CSS 3 standard and is what does the trick :-)

Answer (score 50):

Most of the previous answer didn't work for me in Firefox 38.0.5.  This did...

```
<div style='padding: 3px; width: 130px; word-break: break-all; word-wrap: break-word;'>
    // Content goes here
</div>
```

Documentation:

- [word-break](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp)
- [word-wrap](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp)

Comment: thanks! this is the only answer that worked  (word-break: break-all;  is what worked to me)

Answer (score 14):

```
white-space: pre-wrap
```

[quirksmode.org/css/whitespace.html](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/whitespace.html)

Comment: dead link.  Please provide a more thorough answer.

Answer (score 14):

Aaron Bennet's solution is working perfectly for me, but i had to remove this line from his code --> `white-space: -pre-wrap;` beacause it was giving an error, so the final working code is the following:

```
.wordwrap { 
   white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS3 */   
   white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */   
   white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */    
   word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE */
}
```

thank you very much

Comment: Aaron Bennett mentioned this same answer 2 years before you. what you did here does not add value.

Comment: Hi, as you can see if you read  both answers again, what i am saying is just that Aaron's solution is ok, but i was getting an error in one of the lines he wrote, so i just changed it to the solution that worked for me. Maybe i should have comment in his answer, i know it, sorry & thanks

Comment: I had to add this "white-space: -pre-wrap" and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

As david mentions, DIVs *do* wrap words by default.

If you are referring to really long strings of text without spaces, what I do is process the string server-side and insert empty spans:

```
thisIsAreallyLongStringThatIWantTo<span></span>BreakToFitInsideAGivenSpace
```

It's not exact as there are issues with font-sizing and such. The span option works if the container is variable in size. If it's a fixed width container, you could just go ahead and insert line breaks.

Comment: @TomHert that's really odd. Though, well, IE. It never works. That said, this was posted 5 years ago. CSS3 now has some better word-wrap options that IE may accomodate https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap

Comment: Yeah I know, I was just shocked by the simplicity of this solution that I had to tried it:)

Answer (score 0):

You can try specifying a width for the div, whether it be in pixels, percentages or ems, and at that point the div will remain that width and the text will wrap automatically then within the div.

Comment: Try setting 10px width... and then use a word longer than 10px