# xy coordinates of caret in iframe

Tags: html, iframe, caret

i am trying to make a wysiwyg editor using iframe i want no scrollbar so text should start appearing on next line when max-width is reached .i need the caret coordinates for that please help me out here

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use a container `DIV` tag inside `iFrame` with fixed width and apply word wrap as suggested in [Is there a way to word-wrap long words in a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638223/is-there-a-way-to-word-wrap-text-in-a-div)