# How to wrap div containing spans containing the text to be wrapped?

Tags: html, css, layout, word-wrap

Given this markup

```
<div>
    <span>foo</span>
    <span>bar</span>
    <span>some really long text with word breaks</span>
    <span>baz</span>
</div>
```

This displays as

```
foo bar some really long text with word breaks baz
```

I want it to display as

```
foo bar some really 
long text with word 
breaks baz
```

Using the answers to these other questions:

- [Make text wrap inside an absolutely positioned div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742019/make-text-wrap-inside-an-absolutely-positioned-div)
- [CSS word-wrapping in div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502500/css-word-wrapping-in-div)

I am able to accomplish this if the `<div>` contains text directly in it. But once the text is split up into `<span>`s inside the ` these techniques no longer work.

Given that I cannot do away with the `<span>`s, how can I go about doing this?

---

EDIT:

Chrome web inspector lists the `<div>`'s current CSS as:

```
color: rgb(0, 105, 173);
display: block;
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 25px;
font-weight: bold;
height: 93px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 208px;
margin-right: 208px;
margin-top: 0px;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: rgb(255, 255, 255) 0px 0px 3px;
width: 300px;
```

Comment: I don't quite see what the problem is: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/57cdP/ Is the `div` going to be absolutely positioned?

Comment: @MarcAudet : I have added width, to no avail. I have listed the current CSS above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you must set the width of that's element.

```
div{
    width: 250px;
    word-wrap: break-word; /*if you want to allow unbreakable words to be broken*/
    display: inline-block; /*The element is placed as an inline element, but it behaves as a block element*/
}
```

[Live demo - JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EpLFr/)

Comment: `display: inline-block` did it for me! not exactly sure why, but CSS has its myterious ways!

Comment: what's the problem? are you want demo for it?

Comment: @ yudha no problem, have given you a check mark since this works.

Answer (score 0):

You should define the width of your div

```
div{width: 120px;}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mk9gF/)

Comment: C-Link : I have added width, to no avail. I have listed the current CSS above

Answer (score 0):

Just try this...

```
div
{

    text-align:justify;
    width:130px;

}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HYbSV/)**