# Split Text in <DIV>

Tags: html, css

I have a very long text without space. For example,

```
<div style="width: 179px">
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
</div>
```

I want to split this text into lines with maximum width 179px. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: look into using <wbr> tags aswell

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638223/is-there-a-way-to-word-wrap-text-in-a-div

the answer

Answer (score 7):

Use CSS.

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Answer (score 2):

This won't work in ALL browsers, but it should at least work for most (this is CSS):

```
#your_div {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  white-space: -pre-wrap;
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the css3 `word-wrap:break-word` property will sort this out for you.

Answer (score 1):

Add the style `word-wrap: break-word;` to the div. It is a CSS3 property that works in ALL browsers (even IE5!)

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the CSS style "word-wrap: break-word;" to the element.

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/xj56D/)

You can also apply WBR tags to the word and it will split it according to those tags.

[Here's an example of that](http://jsfiddle.net/xj56D/1/)
[Learn more about wbr tags](http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest `word-wrap: break-word`

Answer (score 1):

Just see below the link,

http://jsfiddle.net/xj56D/2/

Answer (score 0):

Use `word-wrap: break-word`:

http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/fS5cX/