# Keep Text Within The Box

Tags: html, css

How can I keep my text within the box class? without the text overflowing on the right of the box. I tried to figure it out for two hours cant seem to get it.

```
<html>
<head>

 <style type="text/css">
.box {
  width:250px;
  padding-top:5px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#336699;
  border-width:1px;
  padding-left:3px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

       <p class="box">
         <span>
           <a href="http://localhost/Latest Artical 1.htm"><b>Latest Artical 1</b></a><br />Blah...Blah...Blah...Blah...Blah...Blah...Blah...Blah...Blah...Blah...<br /><br />
           <a href="http://localhost/Latest Artical 2.htm"><b>Latest Artical 2</b></a><br />Blah...Blah...Blah...Blah...Blah...Blah...Blah...Blah...Blah...Blah...<br /><br />
           <a href="http://localhost/Latest Artical 5.htm"><b>Latest Artical 5</b></a><br />Blah...Blah...Blah...Blah...Blah...Blah...Blah...Blah...Blah...Blah...<br /><br />
        </span>
       </p>   

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to word-wrap text in a div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638223/is-there-a-way-to-word-wrap-text-in-a-div)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got it right, it will work when you have spaces in the text

http://jsfiddle.net/6sqPG/

Comment: Thanks Greg I see what I was doing wrong now it thought it was one long word.

Comment: You should add `word-wrap: break-word;` like @ChamikaSandamal [said](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9355705/585552) though

Comment: also check [$().dotdotdot](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/) out if you're using jQuery

Answer (score 3):

use this code, `word-wrap: break-word;`

```
.box {
  width:250px;
  padding-top:5px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#336699;
  border-width:1px;
  padding-left:3px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/D2u2K/

Answer (score 0):

You can add [overflow-x](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-x.asp) property, which your text is still **within** the box, but it will have a scroll bar within this if the content is exceeding the width of the box. Something like the code formatting in the question you asked.

```
overflow-x: scroll;
```