# Text wrapping in an absolutely positioned element with no width

Tags: html, css

I have an element structure like this:

`<div><span></span>My text goes here</div>`

both the div and span are positioned absolutely i want the div to expand out to a certain point then wrap to the next line after say 200px.

At the moment the text breaks pretty much after every other word to a new line, i can fix this by using `white-space: nowrap`however this stops the text from wrapping at all.

How can i get the text the wrap but after a certain width?

Comment: Please provide a [reduced test case](http://css-tricks.com/reduced-test-cases/) on [dabblet](http://dabblet.com/) or [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Try using `max-width: 200px;` for your `div`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638223/is-there-a-way-to-word-wrap-text-in-a-div

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'v got it, but why you don't just put the div width: 200px;?