# Div getting overflowed not making separate line

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [wordwrap a very long string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856307/wordwrap-a-very-long-string)

My code

```
<div style="width:40px;">adfdddddddddddddddddddd</div>
```

This code should make 4 lines but it is displaying the output in one line.

Comment: AFAIK = As Far As I Know. Not very much, obviously. :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
<div style="width:40px;word-wrap:break-word;">adfdddddddddddddddddddd</div>;
```

Answer (score 2):

For word wrap consider adding this class.

```
.wordwrap { 
   white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS3 */   
   white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */    
   white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera <7 */   
   white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */    
   word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE */
}
```

See the reference here [Is there a way to word-wrap long words in a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638223/is-there-a-way-to-word-wrap-text-in-a-div)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is showing the output in one line because it's taking the content as a single word. 
A single word will be shown in a single line. Try this code using some sentence then you will get the desired output.
You can try something like the following

```
<div style="width:40px;">This is a sentence.</div>
```

Comment: You also need to learn about this with me

Comment: @Webtecher: yeah you r right, I need to. Answer of BobTodd is perfect