# How to wrap text inside an iframe with designMode on, using css and also javascript if necessary?

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, word-wrap

Any simple solution to this dilemma? I've tried [this possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638223/is-there-a-way-to-word-wrap-text-in-a-div), but it didn't seem to work inside iframes.

Help?

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/zzdZ8/)

**EDIT:** I've searched myself online, and they all say specify a percentage. But I don't initially have content in it, and I set designMode to 'On'. Just to mention to filter out useless answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ha, solved! Used javascript:

```
myiframe.document.body.style.wordWrap = 'break-word';
```

that did it when put into `window.onload`.

Solved, finally!

Answer (score 0):

In CSS you could do it by using 
`word-wrap: break-word;`