# The word-wrap property does not seem to work in CSS

Tags: php, html, css

I have designed an html iframe where I want to use the word-wrap property, i.e., it should break long words onto the next line. But what happens instead is that for long words, it adds a horizontal scroll-bar rather than breaking the word onto the next line.

I tried hiding the scroll bar by using "overflow:hidden" property , but nothing happens.

I could use some help here.

Here's the html code for iframe:

```
<div id="main_frame" >
<iframe id="main_frame" src="homedept.php" name="iframe_a"></iframe>
</div>
```

The CSS is:

```
div#main_frame
{
 float: left;
margin-top:198px;
margin-left:5px;
float:left;
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:900px;
z-index: 0;
word-wrap:break-word;
}

iframe#main_frame
{
float:left;
margin-left: 30px;
margin-right: 300px;
float:left;
border:none;
word-wrap:break-word;
width: 78%;
height:70%;
z-index: 1;

}
```

Thanks for the reply @tyriar, I have set the word-wrap property to the original page now. Still nothing happens.

```
<div id="display_posts">


<?php //php echoes some text here ?>

</div>
```

The CSS code is:

```
#display_posts
{
word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/q/11482115/1577396

Answer (score 0):

You can't apply `word-wrap` to an `iframe`, it's a completely separate page and styles from your original page won't apply. You would need to change the styles on the page where the `iframe` points.

Also `id` attributes must be unique, you have set `id="main_frame"` on both an `iframe` and a `div`.

### Update

If `word-wrap:break-all` is on the `iframe` then maybe the width of the page is introducing the scroll bar. Make sure that your elements scale down correctly with the page. If you load up the page in your `iframe` in your browser you should be able to reduce the window size without a horizontal scroll bar appearing. If one does then it's an issue with the minimum width of that page.

Answer (score 0):

You defined same `ID 2 times` , but `ID` must be `unique` , you can not declare it twice.

So use `class` instead of using `ID`

Also `iframe` call other page and you defined `word-wrap` in original page so its not apply.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`word-break:break-word`

or

`word-break:break-all`

And try using class instead of ID because ID should be unique.