# div container: limit to text going on one line to right

Tags: css, html

I tried adjusting the width in several places of my CSS, but the text keeps on flowing on one line and doesn't wrap within a "leftsidebar".  There seems to be no limit as to how far my text goes to the right, and I want there to be a limit.  How do I set that in CSS?

```
<h3> JKHJKHJKHKJHJKHJKHJKHKJHJKHJKHKJH</h3> 


#leftsidebar {
  position:fixed; 
  width: 160px; 
  top:150px; 
  margin:0px;
  line-height:165%; 
  white-space:nowrap; 
  z-index:50; 
  padding: 0px 35px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4uxcN/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to word-wrap text in a div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638223/is-there-a-way-to-word-wrap-text-in-a-div)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `white-space:nowrap;` (and eventually add `word-wrap: break-word;` to respect your div boundaries with your no-spaced long word) to send the text to new lines;

add `overflow-x: scroll;` if you instead want the text in one single line but want to have an horizontal scrollbar inside your fixed width div: http://jsfiddle.net/4uxcN/10/

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about `word-wrap: break-word` property it will break the word when it reaches the end of the parent width.

Answer (score 1):

Remove {white-space:nowrap;}, which forces your text to one line and add {word-wrap: break-word} to deal with your very long word.

http://jsfiddle.net/4uxcN/6/

```
#leftsidebar {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, there are 3 ways you can do it:

1. Just remove your `white-space` property. [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/4uxcN/7/)
2. Remove `white-space` property, and add `word-wrap: break-word;` property. [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/4uxcN/8/)
3. Set you `white-space` to `pre-wrap` instead of `nowrap`. [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/4uxcN/9/)

Answer (score 1):

If you remove

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

All text will break at the spaces to fit within the box width.

Super long strings like the one in you example will not break. To force stupid long strings to break you can use.

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

also you could use an overflow property Like

```
overflow:scroll
```

It just really depends on the layout you are going for