# nicEdit does not wrap text

Tags: wysiwyg, nicedit

How can I make a text wrap on a text area with nicEdit implemented. When editor is on the textarea
the attribute is not working and textarea does not break line ?

Answer (score 0):

You must add wrap to the nicEdit main div.

Look here for wrap [Is there a way to word-wrap long words in a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638223/is-there-a-way-to-word-wrap-text-in-a-div)

```
$("div.nicEdit-main").addClass('wordwrap');
```

See example on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LfxGm/