# Text come out of div when set div's width by percentage

Tags: html, css

This is my html:

```
<div class="targetdiv">My Text that come out of div</div>
<style>
  .targetdiv{
     width: 24%;
     border: 1px solid red;
  }
</style>
```

with the above design my text come out of div. But if I change the `width` and use pixel instead of percentage every thing would be OK:

```
<style>
  .targetdiv{
     width: 190px;
     border: 1px solid red;
  }
</style>
```

So how could I use percentage in `width` and my text remain inside of div? any suggestion?

Comment: the percentage is related to the width of the parent. So you need to wrap the targetDiv inside a wrapper with fixed length

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan But I cant set the fixed length

Comment: how does the text "come out of div"? This html should just break line and grow in height. http://jsfiddle.net/8SJ8E/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this class:

```
<style>
.targetdiv {
       width: 190px;
       border: 1px solid red;
       white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS3 */   
       white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */    
       white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera <7 */   
       white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */    
       word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE */
    }
</style>
```

Original answer was posted by **Aaron Bennett** here: [Is there a way to word-wrap long words in a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638223/is-there-a-way-to-word-wrap-text-in-a-div)

And here is a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/LRpve/

Comment: As I mentioned I need to use percentage in width, so the width be `24%` and in this case your answer not worked