# How to make a paragraph reside within a div

Tags: css

Text is going beyond the div. How can I enforce the paragraph that won't overflow outside the div ?

```css
.preview {
    background: red;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="preview">
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
</div>
```

Comment: remove the width in your css and it will fill the entire paragraph. I presume that is what you are asking...

Comment: You have already filled the div by that paragraph. What do you mean?

Comment: @HashemQolami The OP's question title help you understand.

Comment: Sorry about the my unclear question. I got the answer from C-link Nepal

Comment: Hence, this is yet another duplicate of [Is there a way to word-wrap long words in a div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638223/is-there-a-way-to-word-wrap-long-words-in-a-div).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use word-wrap:

```css
.preview {
    background: red;
    width: 200px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="preview">
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
</div>
```

Comment: And add padding so that the paragraph wont be too close to the edges of the div.